# Android Emulator is not working with windows 10 pro 1803

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

My android emulator is showing an error again and again that android emulator is incompatible with hyper-V . I tried to solve by trying all the methods available on the internet but nothing work for me.

Screenshot:-
[image: Here is the screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried Hyper-V enabled Android emulator? Check their [blog here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2018/05/08/hyper-v-android-emulator-support/)

Comment: Hyper-V is not actually required for the emulators if you can use [Intel HAXM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-intel-haxm).